# Sublimelinter 3 cppcheck configuration

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I have installed `SublimeText 2` on Ubuntu (14.01) and also `Sublimelinter 3` from Package Control list(Ctrl+Shift+P). I have also installed `cppcheck`.
Now I need help to "activate" the linker in live c++ code. I haven't found what exactly I have to type in Settings-user.
How do I get SublimeLinter-cppcheck option from Package Control list?
I would be thankful for any help.